# Problem with JsonResult exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have controller action which returns JsonResult and is consumed by jquery ajax get request. All works well on my well my dev machine but when copied on production hosting I get below exception on last line controller action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult Single(int UNIQUE_NO) {
  ...
  return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  // < here exception is thrown
}
```

Method not found: 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json(System.Object, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior)'.

Exception is being captured by ELHAM.

Platform: ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta

Dlls included with app (Copy local : true):
Microsoft.Web.Mvc, MvcContrib, MvcContrib.FluentHtml, MvcContrib.TestHelper, Rhino.Mocks, System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Routing

What is going on here? What/Where should I be looking for this?
(as mentioned above I dont get this exception on my dev machine where json result object is generated as expected and returned to caller)

Here is call stack (ELMAH):

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json(System.Object, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior)'.
   at NN_AccessToWeb_MVC2.Controllers.HomeController.Single(Int32 UNIQUE_NO)
   at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__7()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassa.<>c__DisplayClassc.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__9()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? It's a very interesting exception you have there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning a new `JsonResult`:

```
return new JsonResult {
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
    Data = /* you model goes here */,
    ContentType = "application/json",
    ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};
```

Comment: Isnt Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) already JsonResult ?

Comment: It is. It's a helper like `View()` is a helper for new'ing up a ViewResult. Perhaps you're not including the right namespaces?

Comment: That throws similar exception> 
System.MissingMethodException
Method not found: 'Void System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.set_JsonRequestBehavior(System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior)'.<
Which namespace(s) could I missing be missing ?

Comment: What namespaces are you including?

Comment: I've added included namespaces in original post.
This is obviously issue with namespaces or similar as I cant recreate exception on dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Json(data, "application/json", Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: return Json(YOURDATA), "application/json" 
                ,Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

ITS WORK WOW